# Java synchronised iterators?

Tags: java, synchronization

I'm looking for a way to call a method that returns from the the called object, an iterable collection, the source (the collection instance in the called object) of which will prevent simultaneous access by other threads.

I would imagine this iterable collection would be wrapped in a class in which was provided a synchronisation mechnanism such that when the caller was finished with the collection it might call a method called finished() that would release the lock on the underlying collection object. Although the API's have the methods that return synchronised versions of common collections, there seems to be no way to programmatically release the lock by calling a finished method; AFAICT the lock appears to be released when the wrapper is garbage collected.

Is there anything that does this in the Java SE API, or is it considered easy enough just to roll something myself?

Thanks for your constructive input.

Comment: AFAIK there's no such API, you'll have to implement it yourself.

Comment: so.. "A collection such that as long as some thread somewhere has a reference to an iterator all other methods of the collection block"?  What happens if a thread passes a reference to an iterator to another thread?  What happens if a thread throws an exception without finishing the iteration?  Maybe you could give an example of using this hypothetical API?

Comment: @Affe Sorry for the vagueness - that's the reason for why I asked the question. I actually want to prevent access to the collection and to any of its elements. Accesses to all methods that touch the collection of the called object will also block until the caller finishes with the iterator.

Comment: WHat do you want to happen if a second thread tries to access the Iterator?  Should they get an Exception?

Comment: @JoseMartinez I hadn't thought about that, so throwing an exception would be appropriate. So, thanks for your answer too, but I think the answer I have ticked promises a better way to look at a solution to my problem overall.

Comment: The other thing that can be added to the my answer is a weakreference so that a thread does not hold lock the access indefinitely in the case that it has an error or no longer holds a reference to the Iterable.  I do not think that you need to skate around your original ask.

Comment: @JoseMartinez Truth be known, I'm still thinking on what I'll use. I've upvoted your answer because it is also very good. I like the one I've ticked because I can do just about anything once I've got the lock, but time will tell which solution I opt for. Maybe I'll use a hybrid of some type. You've given me stuff to work with, so thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't practical to pass a reference to the iterator back to a caller and try to internally block other methods until the caller is done with the iterator.  What if the calling thread never finishes iterating due to some error?  What if the calling Thread 1 then passes the ierator reference off to another Thread 2.  Thread 2 is probably going to block forever because Thread 1 gave it an object that Thread 1 is holding the lock on!

Either the calling thread needs to be a participant in actively acquiring and releasing the lock, or you need to invert control and instead of giving back an iterator, take in the code you plan to iterate over so that you can be in control of your lock boundaries.

e.g.,

```
public class TestIt {

    public static class ListWrapper<K> {
        private List<K> list = new ArrayList<>();

        public synchronized void add(K value) {
            list.add(value);
        }

        public synchronized void executeOperation(Operation<K> operation) {
            for (K k: list) {
                operation.execute(k);
            }
        }

    }

    public static interface Operation<K> {
        void execute(K value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListWrapper<String> strings = new ListWrapper<>();
        strings.add("FOO");
        strings.add("BAR");
        strings.executeOperation(new Operation<String>() {
            @Override
            public void execute(String value) {
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although I don't think it entirely answers my question, you've managed to pull me in another direction which I hadn't considered. Certainly, what I was considering would probably give the caller too much rope. I wasn't expecting the caller to pass the collection to another thread, but that is indeed something to be mindful in a future where I might have.

Comment: While I really like the suggestion, in my opinion it also suffers from the original problem of blocking. Imagine the executeOperation implementation provided, also waits indefinitely on a resource or causes a deadlock. I would prefer exposing a Fail-Safe iterator with an annotation on it to denote its an expensive operation.

Answer (score 0):

The Java SDK does have the `Collections.synchronizedXXX` methods, which wrap a synchronized block around every method. That won't help if you want multiple methods to be guarded by the same lock until you say you're explicitly done.

You can use a `RenentrantLock` to the same effect though and an extended `Collection` interface with the `finished` method:

```
public interface ExtendedLockCollection<T> extends Collection<T> {
    public void finished();
}
```

And then you can create a utility method (like the various `Collections` methods) to create the proxy implmentation, something like this:

```
public static <T> ExtendedLockCollection<T> extendedLockCollection(final Collection<T> wrapped) {
    return new ExtendedLockCollection<T>() {
        RentrantLock extendedLock = new ReentrantLock();

        public void add(T value) {
            start();
            wrapped.add(value);
        }

        // ... etc for the remaining Collection methods ...

        private void start() {
            synchronized(extendedLock) {
                if(!extendedLock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
                    extendedLock.lock();
                }
            }
        }

        public void finished() {
            if(extendedLock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
                extendedLock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unless I'm missing something, that should about do it. You can create methods like this for the other collection types you want support, like the `Collections.synchronizedXXX` methods.

EDIT: This only applies to the collection. Access to the member's methods is not synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be it.  Its a wrapper to an Iterable, as you requested.  Just pass it the Collection you want it to wrap.  It will allow access to the first thread that tries to use it.  When that thread is done with it then it will call finish and the Iterable will be free to be used by another thread.  The key here is tracking which thread has it, and synchronizing access to the reference to that thread.

```
public class LockedIterable implements Iterable {

    private final Collection collection;
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private Thread threadWithAccess;
    private final MyIterator iterator;

    public LockedIterable(Collection collection) {
        this.collection = collection;
        this.iterator = new MyIterator(collection);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator iterator() {
        tryLock();
        return iterator;
    }

    public void finished() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            threadWithAccess = null;
        }
    }

    private static class SimultanousAccessException extends RuntimeException {

        public SimultanousAccessException() {
        }
    }

    private class MyIterator implements Iterator {

        Iterator it;

        private MyIterator(Collection collection) {
            it = collection.iterator();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            tryLock();
            return it.hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public Object next() {
            tryLock();
            return it.next();
        }

    }

    private void tryLock() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (threadWithAccess == null) {
                threadWithAccess = Thread.currentThread();
            } else if (!threadWithAccess.equals(Thread.currentThread())) {
                throw new SimultanousAccessException();
            }
        }
    }

}
```